# Typescript react image src require produces Error Cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to get an image src from inside the react component with typescript however I get the error Cannot find module

```
<Image
   src={require(`../../assets/img/Products/${product._attributes.PictureIdle}`)}
/>

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './cafe_barista_1.png'
at webpackContextResolve (.*$:53)
at webpackContext (.*$:48)
at Ble.tsx:118
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at Ble (Ble.tsx:112)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
at react-dom.development.js:11327
at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21893)
at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:16139)
at parseXml (Ble.tsx:88)
```

can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the exact error message please

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is related to webpack configuration. Do you have this file in your build: "'./cafe_barista_1.png'"?

Comment: yes the file exists here ../../assets/img/Products/, Please note I created the app with npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript

Comment: Would this work if you hardcode this file name instead of dynamic string?

Comment: I don't get the error anymore but I don't see the image either, upon inspection I see from the generated Html and the src of the image is [object Module]

Comment: Maybe this should be `require().default`?

Comment: require().default works if I hardcode the name but I get the same error Error Cannot find module if I use the dynamic string